# itext 7 - RTL language

Tags: c#, itext7

I'm using iText7 and pdfHTML add-on to create accessible pdf. I need to write Arabic texts in the pdf. Added below code in HTML file.

```
<p align="right" class="fontTimes">أسبوع</P>
```

C# code:

```
LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile("itextkey.xml");

    IList<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(htmlFile,converterProperties);
    foreach(IElement element in elements){
        doc.Add((IBlockElement)element);
    }
```

Included itext.tyography.dll to the solution. But it is written and LTR language. Please help me to solve the issue. 
Thanks

Comment: Please show us how you included itext.typography.dll into your solution. Are you sure you activated the (trial) license key? Without the license key, all text will be written from left-to -ight. The writing system will only change to right-to-left after the license key is activated. Please show us your C# code.

Comment: I'm using activated (trial) license key. and updated the question with C# code. I added itext.tyography.dll  as project references.

Comment: I don't see the code where you activate the trial license. Is it because you forgot to copy/paste it in your question? Or is it because it's missing in your code? If it's missing in your code, you have the reason why LTR isn't working.

Comment: LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile("itextkey.xml"); used this line to load license key. And the License file is loaded successfully.

Comment: When I convert HTML with Arabic text including the typography add-on, my code works. The only problem I can think of is that you have the wrong `itextkey.xml` in the sense that some keys only work for iText 7 and not for the add-ons.